# Change Serial Number (ro.serialno) on Android Virtual Device (Emulator) on Apple Silicon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-silicon

I need to change the **Serial Number** (*ro.serialno*, and other IDs) of an emulated Android Device (Android Studio 2021 Preview). There are not many ressources concerning that issue.

Ideas:

- Change it by adb shell (*setprop ro.serialno=123*), but it is a read only property
- Add serial number by kernel parameters, but the Android Emulator will overwrite them.
- Change the Number by editing the emulator (or virtual device) in a hex editor. But I could not find, where it is stored

Do you have any ideas?

Environment:
MacBook M1, Android 11, arm64-v8a (Api-Level 30)

Thank you very much!

**Update**
Running emulator with -prop...

```
emulator -avd my_device -prop ro.serialno=123456 -no-snapshot-load
```

... leads to warning:

> WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('ro.serialno=123456'), only
> 'qemu.*' properties are supported